# C# Library for converting Shapefile Projection

Tags: c#, shapefile, .net, coordinate-system

Is there any C# library which can take a shapefile as an input with projection information defined (e.g, EPSG 3011) and return a new shapefile with user specified projection (e.g, EPSG 4326) ?

Answer (score 4):

GDAL/OGR has [C# bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp). You might want to check it out. Alternatively, you might also want to check [dotspatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/). The dotspatial page has [sample code](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Projecting%20to%20USA%20Contiguous%20Lambert%20Conformal%20Conic&referringTitle=UseKnownCoordinateSystems) on reprojecting a shape file.

---

You can do this in ogr ( It's provided in the [FWTools package](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) ). No need to code in C#.

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:3011 -t_srs EPSG:4326 outfile.shp infile.shp
```

Thanks @iant for pointing it out.

Comment: OK! is there any piece of code you may know, which could take shapefile as an input ?

Comment: ogr2ogr will do this

Comment: @user1899 Why does it have to be a C# library btw?

Comment: As i understand it is command line tool, But I need to change shapefile projection within my web C# application code. How I use ogr2ogr in my C# code?

Comment: @user1899 Use the C# bindings for that.